# Make exception to whole-site RedirectMatch rule

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, regex

We have this RedirectMatch rule to move clients on the SSL enabled site while maintaining the path they're trying to access:

```
Redirectmatch permanent (.*) https://www.foobar.com$1
```

and it is working perfectly. Now we would like to add an exception for /somepath that should *not* be redirected. How can I do that?

With mod_rewrite I would add a rewriterule saying "don't rewrite and stop matching", but there isn't such mechanism with redirect. Also, if I trivially reverse the regexp like !(/somepath|/someotherpath) it would no longer get the $1 parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you don't want to use mod_rewrite?

You could mimic the functionality with this:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(somepath|someotherpath)
RewriteRule  (.*)                       $1                        [R=permanent]
RewriteRule  http://%{SERVER_NAME}(.*)  https://www.foobar.com$1  [L]
```

---

I hadn't realized Apache uses PCRE.  Since it does, you can do this bit of voodoo to do what you want with mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/?((?!(thisisfoo|thisisbar)).*) https://www.foobar.com/$1
```

where /thisisfoo and /thisisbar are exceptions to the redirect.

Comment: mod_rewrite is never the answer to whole-site problems.

Comment: @adaptr: I agree 100%, eventually you get mounds of convoluted match rules, the whole thing becomes a mess.  Plus mod_rewrite requires more resources, and executes before all mod_alias declarations.  So mod_rewrite is extremely powerful, but flexibility always comes at a cost.  Sometimes it's the best tool for the job, but it seems like everyone just copies/pastes mod_rewrite rules for everything.

Comment: @adaptr, So are you indicating that this answer is awful/not recommended?  Or am I misunderstanding your comment. That's fine, either way. If the former, then I would really like insight on what your recommended/proposed solution is. Without an alternative here, I'm about to do something very much like this. But if there is a better way, I'd *really* like to know! DevOps and Server stuff is *hard* to figure out. Way More so than front/back end, IMHO.

Comment: Also, @j-m-becker, maybe you could weigh in on this (my question above)? - Sounds like you're maybe ok, with the above solution, but maybe not? Really just trying to understand.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation (at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#order), `Redirect`s are proccessed in the order they are encountered. So you would want to put your more restrictive rule first, and then have your catch-all rule at the end.

Comment: Which works great, assuming your narrowly scoped declaration is a redirect.  In this particular question, it's not a redirect, it's an exception to the site-wide redirect.  Still a great tip, just not an answer related to the OP.  On the other hand, this would make a great comment.

Answer (score 1):

I landed here before I found correct answer for my situation, so I'm adding my solution for reference.

I needed to redirect everything **except** two folders, I'm calling them `files1` and `files2` in the example below:

`RedirectMatch permanent "^(/(?!(files1/|files2/)).*)" https://www.example.com$1`

Likewise word `permanent` can be replaced by `301` which is essentially the same ("permanent" in HTTP code), or with `302` (which means temporary redirect).